# using phpmailer in freebsd and having errors

Tags: phpmailer, freebsd

SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (684708780)

I have seen the answer many times for use with window servers which I have one running but in this case i have this being used in a UNIX freeBSD server. I have been looking for the answer for some time now. this is the mail script I am using.

Comment: Read the docs and use your package manager to install or compile a PHP ssl module, and enable it in your php.ini.

Comment: The only thing I have seen is the big install of open ssl. When I installed this on windows server all I had to do is edit the php.ini

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FreeBSD's package manager, try:

```
pkg install php56-openssl
```